# Share extension to after coming host app breakpoints are not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, printing, breakpoints

From Share extension (SLComposeServiceViewController) to after coming host app breakpoints are not working in swift And Printing also not working !!!!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userDefault = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.abcd.sharecontent1")
    if let dict = userDefault?.value(forKey: "storedURLData"){

        let data = (dict as AnyObject).value(forKey: "urlData") as! Data
        let nameStr = (dict as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name") as! String
        print("Data is :- ", data)
        print("Name is :- ", nameStr)

        // Here nameStr data is going to Label but not printing
        self.lblText.text = nameStr

        // This print nameStr is not working
        print("NameStr is :-", nameStr)

        // Data to Swift Dictionary
        do {
            let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as! NSDictionary
            print("dictionary :-", dictionary)
        }
        catch {
            // catch error.
        }
        userDefault?.removeObject(forKey: "storedURLData")
        userDefault?.synchronize()
    } else {
        print("The value for key called storedURLData does not exist.")
    }
}
```

Not calling breakpoints and printing

Answer (score 0):

If this view has already been displayed without being deallocated, the `viewDidLoad` method only gets called once.

My recommendation to you is to move your code into a method of it's own and call that method.

Second if you only need this data once, call that method from your `viewDidLoad` method. If you need this data updated each time you return to this view, call it from either the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods, depending on how you are using this data (eg. you are leaving the view for another view and returning back).

Third, if your breakpoint is not being hit and the print statements are not displaying, it means that the `if let dict = userDefault?.value(forKey:"storedURLData"){` content does not exist. Your print statements and breakpoints inside the `if let dict = ..` will only be hit if `dict` exists and has a value. Chances are you don't have a value for the key called `storedURLData` or there is a spelling mistake for that key.

Put a breakpoint after declaring your `userDefault` to inspect what is inside that object and confirm that your key `storedURLData` exists. The best way to find out if you're unclear whether the value you want exists would be like so:

```
if let dict = .... {
    // All of your code for when the dict exists
} else {
    print("The value for key called storedURLData does not exist.")
}
```

If the else statement prints out, put a breakpoint there and inspect your `userDefaults` object.

Comment: Hlo, i'm able store to label of inside dict loop .

Comment: @GSreekanth I am unsure what you mean. See my update for a little more help.

Comment: Just now updated my question look at and `if let dict = userDefault?.value(forKey: "storedURLData"){
        let data = (dict as AnyObject).value(forKey: "urlData") as! Data        
        let nameStr = (dict as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name") as! String        
        print("Data is :- ", data)         
        // Here nameStr data is going to Label but not printing    
        self.lblText.text = nameStr             
        // This print nameStr is not working            
        print("NameStr is :-", nameStr)             
        userDefault?.synchronize()       
    }`

Comment: @GSreekanth - Did you add the `else` statement?